# Will my domain setup (GoDaddy) work with Github pages CDN?

Tags: dns, godaddy, github

I've registered an Apex domain (example.com) on GoDaddy.
I'd like to link it to a project page (`gh-pages` branch).

My GoDaddy setup is as follows:

- Two A records that point to Github IPs.
- A CNAME record for `www` subdomain that points to my github pages URL (without the `/project-name` part).

My Github setup is:

- A repository with a `gh-pages` branch (`/project-name`)
- A CNAME file in this branch that points to `example.com`

After reading Github Pages docs and other answers on SO for an hour or so I'm still confused:

- Will the site work both for `example.com` and `www.example.com` URLs?
- Will I benefit from Github's CDN and DoS protection.

If not I'd really appreciate further advice or reference information.

[image: My GoDaddy Setup]

Comment: You should be able to do this, though I am not an expert, we have knowledgeable people on just that topic. Even then, I am sure we have answered this question before one way or another. This list should help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=godaddy+github

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks, I've seen this info but there are no clear cut answers about the issues I brought up here.

Comment: I am not sure about the second question, but yes to the first question. Why did you need two `A` records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the site work both for example.com and www.example.com URLs?

Yes it will work because you have setup both A records and CNAME records in your Godaddy account. Your current CNAME file in your github pages is this `example.com` hence it will redirect your `www.example.com` visors to `example.com`. If you have used `www.example.com` in CNAME(Github) file then it will redirect all visitor from `example.com` to `www.example.com`. Hope it will clear your doubt.

> Will I benefit from Github's CDN and DoS protection.

Well your current setting points that, you're using apex domain. And github 
recommended to use [www as CNAME, if you want to get benefits from their CDN](https://help.github.com/articles/about-supported-custom-domains/#www-subdomains). So no benefits if you've used apex or custom domain like(blog.example.com).

Comment: Thank you very much! So it means that if I want to benefit from Github's features I need to change the CNAME file in my Github repo to point to `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`? Is there anything else I need to do in the Godaddy account?

Comment: No, just use www in CNAME, and everything will be fine.